# How can I create a Watch in Gulp to update when a JSON file changes

Tags: json, gulp, gulp-watch

I can't seem to get my watch to fire on JSON files. Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong? The task works if I run it manually...

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rename = require("gulp-rename");

var localizationDestination = './wwwroot/localization';

gulp.task('copy-localization', function (resolve) {
    gulp.src('./modules/*/localization/*.json')
        .pipe(rename({ dirname: '' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(localizationDestination));
    resolve();
});

gulp.task('watch', function (resolve) {
    gulp.watch('./modules/*/localization/*.json', gulp.series(['copy-localization']));
    resolve();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series([
    'copy-localization',
    'watch']
));
```

Comment: Check here I think you're calling subdirectories incorrectly: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/how-to-use-gulp/video/gulp-watch-example - double asterix ** is js syntax, and in Gulp it means "This indicates to look in any and all sub directories, including the top level directory. ".

Comment: Yeah I tried the ** as well... it's weird that this works in the gulp.src(...) but the exact same thing in the gulp.watch(...) does not. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll just hard code the sub directories for the time being. If anyone else has any thoughts it would be great to have it working properly.

Comment: The globstar `**` does work in both `gulp.src` and `gulp.watch` statements.  A single `*` would be a folder with a single character as its name.

Comment: Gulp specifies - * Matches any amount - including none - of characters within a single segment. Useful for globbing files within one directory. https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs . As I said works as a source not as a watch...